# Is it possible to override OnLoad in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, overriding

Currently, I use an ApplicationController.vb class to override OnActionExecuted for data that is repeated throughout my application.

However, in relation to the question [Session variables not saving on initial page load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5434033/147145), I was wondering if it was possible to override the OnLoad/Page_Load event in the same manner in the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such events in ASP.NET MVC. Plus, are you sure you override the correct method? Maybe, `OnActionExecuting` will be a better choice?

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not certain of the difference. This is the first time I've fiddled around with this in MVC at least.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no concept of Page in ASP.NET MVC there is no `OnLoad` nor `PageLoad`.